# Deploy Workflow as template?

Tags: list, workflow, deployment, site-template

I have a workflow that resides in a visual studio 2010 solution. Its a state machine workflow for a list.

Currently the workflow is deploy at the root site, using a root lists (customlist, task, history) and i am wondering if i can somehow create a new sub site and then have that workflow point to the new list in the sub site somehow.

Thanks alot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Reusable Workflow then you can always use it in the sub sites.

Comment: any ressource that would explain that ?

Comment: This should help buddy, http://plexhosted.com/billing/knowledgebase/255/How-to-create-a-reusable-workflow-in-SharePoint-Designer-SharePoint-2010.html